# How to use I feel like

Tags: grammaticality

I want to go for wine and tapas, it's correct to say this?
- I feel like wine and tapas.
- I feel like I want wine and tapas.
- What about going for wine and tapas?

Comment: Yes, any of those. "I feel like wine and tapas" is definitely idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can say

1) I feel like having wine and tapas.

2) I feel like going for wine and tapas.

3) I feel like wine and tapas.

The third sentence uses an understood gerund, whether it's *eating* or *having*, etc.  after *feel like*.

[Garner's Modern English Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1608&lpg=PT1608&dq="feel+like+pizza"+meaning&source=bl&ots=7xTi3QjCUc&sig=Piij5eBBsRJFNsQPCVqiTvJftlM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6zpvxl-zWAhXJ6iYKHddgCTMQ6AEIaDAP#v=onepage&q=%22feel%20like%20pizza%22%20meaning&f=false)

explains that using *feel like* before a food is "perfectly grammatical" and "not at all substandard". That the object of *like* is the understood (i.e., elided) gerund *eating* and that the object of eating is the food substance.

[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/feel-like-something)

> **feel like something**
>
> to have a desire to do or have something:
>
> I feel like Chinese food.

[Word Reference](http://daily.wordreference.com/2017/03/27/basic-word-of-the-day-feel/)

> If you feel like something, it can also mean that you want to have it or to do it.
>
> I feel like pizza for dinner.

See also the dialog at  [ESL Fast](https://www.eslfast.com/easydialogs/ec/restaurant01.htm):

> A: Let's go out to eat.
>   B: That sounds like fun.
>   A: Where do you want to go?
>   B: Let me think a minute.
>   A: I feel like Chinese.
>   B: That sounds delicious.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how wine and tapas feels.
I don't know that I would like to feel wine and tapas.

If I wanted to both eat tapas and drink wine, I would want to *have* some wine to drink and some tapas to eat.

Therefore; either form, "**I feel like** I want to have some wine and tapas;" or, "**I feel like** having some wine and tapas," would work and preserve the "**I feel like**" construction.

Comment: Remarks such as "I feel like an apple" are perfectly normal in British English, though they invite the facetious response "You don't look like one!"